# Microsoft Visual Studio version not updating in Control Panel

Tags: c#, visual-studio

The Microsoft Visual Studio version in UI (Help – About Microsoft Visual Studio) does not match the actual Microsoft Visual Studio version in Control Panel, does anyone know how to fix this in Control Panel?

e.g for VS 2015 update 3 version from UI is 14.0.25431.01
and in control panel the VS 2015 update 3 version is 14.0.25420.1

I would appreciate any help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Visual Studio is not in the control panel. Can you far more specific?

Comment: @Jazimov In Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features > Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015 with Updates

Comment: Can you explain why you care?  Are you looking for a way of determining which version is installed without having to launch Visual Studio?

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, I reported it in the Jenkins console logs..It is very important for the QA team and making the build.

Comment: @JanTamm: Something to think about: Forget about Visual Studio version; it does not affect the build.  Instead, record the compiler version.  It's been years since you could predict compiler version from Visual Studio version; now there is toolchain support which allows the latest Visual Studio update to keep running a specific (older) compiler version.

Comment: That is, the data you want is "Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24215.1 for x86" or "Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.7.2558.0"   As a bonus, Jenkins can get those just by running `cl.exe` or `csc.exe` and doesn't have to go through contortions of reading from the Uninstall list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, Microsoft published two updates to Visual Studio 2015 Update 3:

```
Update 3 (original version) 14.0.25420.10   Date: 09/14/2016
Update 3 (newer patch)      14.0.25431.01   Date: 08/02/2016
```

They actually updated the update! So it wasn't a typical update. Thus, the control panel Programs and Features section lists the original Update 3 version even though the IDE lists the newer patch version number. In a way that makes some sense because the new patch only updated the IDE, but it would probably have been a better idea for Microsoft to just release an Update 4 and update the version numbers in the control panel Programs and Features section as well as in the IDE.

Reference [Version Numbers]:
https://www.ryadel.com/en/visual-studio-build-numbers-version-id-default-path-all-releases-vs6-vs2015/

Reference [Release Notes]:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt752379.aspx

Comment: But the "Add/Remove Programs" list is not a valid method of creating a software inventory anyway, so in the end it doesn't matter.

Comment: Agreed--but I saw no reference to "software inventory" in the OP. All I saw was a question as to why there might be a mismatch in the version numbers...